# Making a label in QGIS using two different attributes

Tags: qgis, labeling, formatting

So I'm currently making a map of ancient Assyrian city names matched with their modern correlates. I uploaded the two names as different attributes starting as different cells in Google Sheets and am wanting to show both cells in the same label with the ancient name on top and the modern name below it in italics.
At first I had both names in the same cell trying to edit that within the software which didn't work, I also tried each line of the label formatting regular options without success. Is what I want possible with this program?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you have two fields, called "OLDNAME" and "NEWNAME" (substitute with your actual field names).

- Open the layer properties,
- Select Labels
- Change the dropdown from "No Labels" to "Single Labels"
- Enter the expression

  - `"OLDNAME" + '<p><i>' +  "NEWNAME" + '</i>'`  or
  - `format('%1 <p> <i>%2</i>', "OLDNAME", "NEWNAME")`
- Check "Allow HTML formatting"

[image]

[image]